# Is it possible for 533MHz PC4200 DDR2 RAM to work on G33 chipset mobo?

Tags: memory, compatibility, ddr2

I have two 512 MB RAM sticks that work @ max 533MHz. Now, I want to buy a mainboard based on Intel's G33 chipset, namely the MSI MS-7502 (produced for Medion). While I found the G33 does not support 533MHz DDR2 memory (it needs at least 667MHz), but the seller claims the mainboard is compatible with 533MHz.

Are there any G33-based mobos that support 533MHz, or is it impossible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support for the DDR2 ram specs are defined as part of the northbridge, if the manufacturer claims that they support 533 Mhz RAM then they support it.. since you are already planning to upgrade to a G33 board, its a good idea to look for a ram which runs faster.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The idea is that I want to reuse my old two 512 MB sticks with another two I bought recenently - these are two 1 GB 667MHz sticks. If the old ones won't work, I will only have 2 GB or memory available..

Comment: you should not mix and match them... if you use 533 MHz stick then use only 533MHz sticks.
here is something which might help explain http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090710135914AAjpbVR

Comment: another discussion on a similar topic http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/268167-12-speed-possible

Comment: Ok, I guess 2 GB of RAM will be enough for a low-mid end Core 2 Duo rig. These 533MHz sticks shall stay with Pentium 4.